# If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are the roots of $x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx + s=0$, find in terms of $p,q,r,s$ the value of $\Sigma\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma }$

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

> If $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are the roots of $x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx + s=0$, find in terms of $p,q,r,s$ the value of $\Sigma\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma }$

My general strategy was transforming the equation to one whose roots are $\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma },etc$ but it seems to be impossible to narrow it down and presents a huge calculation.

Next, I tried simplifying the expression $\Sigma \frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma }$ but, it doesn't turn out favourable as a huge calculation appears which couldn't be simplified more and no desirable form was obtained and this was in vain too. I don't understand how to approach it...

Comment: Use, for example, `$\alpha$` for $\alpha$.

Comment: @Shaun Yeah, I usually do that but I dont know how did the symbol came auto -generated. Just for curiosity : is the formatting of alpha as done by me and in the usual way, made any difference?  Maybe, the difference isn't viewable in the  software version of the browser I am using...Also, how to understand whether someone wrote them in the usual tex way or the notation appended within two $$ ?

Comment: Some devices do not render, say, α.

Comment: @Shaun Ohh...I get it ...Next time, I will keep it in mind. Thanks! This was a confusion , I had for a long time 

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by $\Sigma\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma }$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I think $\Sigma \frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}+\frac{\alpha\gamma}{\beta}+\frac{\gamma\beta}{\alpha}+...$  Actually, it was given like this in the question...

Comment: @David Quinn As it was presented like this in the question, I myself am not sure about it. Apparently, I found this problem on a handout and the source is unknown to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^4+px^3+qx^2+rx+s$
$=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)$
$=x^4-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)x^3+(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma+\beta\delta+\gamma\delta)x^2-(\alpha\beta\gamma+\alpha\beta\delta+\alpha\gamma\delta+\beta\gamma\delta)x+\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$

So we have:
$p=-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)$
$q=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma+\beta\delta+\gamma\delta$
$r=-(\alpha\beta\gamma+\alpha\beta\delta+\alpha\gamma\delta+\beta\gamma\delta)$
$s=\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$

This implies:

$$\sum\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}=\frac{q(-r)-3s(-p)}{s}=3p-\frac{qr}{s}$$

Comment: How did you conclude $$\sum\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}=\frac{q(-r)-3s(-p)}{s}=3p-\frac{qr}{s}$$ ?

Comment: @Franklin I wrote the sigma expression as a single fraction, then related the numerator to $p, q, r, s$.

Comment: Please elaborate upon the calculations. How could you add $24$ fractions ? As $\Sigma\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}$ contains $\binom42\binom41=24$ terms if I am not wrong .

Comment: In $\Sigma\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}$, in each term, the numerator does not contain the term in the denominator, so there are $\binom32\binom41=12$ terms. If that's not what you mean, perhaps you can explain exactly what you mean by $\Sigma\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}$.

Comment: Ok, but adding $12$ terms is enormous. How did you perform it?

Comment: When you have some experience with these kinds of questions, you can see patterns. (Same could be said about lots of types of questions.)

Comment: Can you enlighten me?

Comment: Write down all the terms in $\sum\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}$. Then write down all the terms in $\frac{q(-r)-3s(-p)}{s}$. Then match the terms one by one.

Comment: If the sum $\Sigma \frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}$ contains $12$ terms can you please elucidate what type of terms you are considering , as somehow I am arriving at $\binom{4}{2}\binom31$ terms ....

Comment: The bottom has 4 choices. Say for example the bottom is d. Then the top could be ab, bc, ab - that's 3 choices. So 4x3=12.

Comment: Great ! I came up with this :$\Sigma \frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}=\frac{(\beta\gamma)^2\delta+(\beta\delta)^2\gamma+(\delta\gamma)^2\beta+(\alpha\gamma)^2\delta+(\alpha\delta)^2\gamma+(\delta\gamma)^2\alpha+(\beta\alpha)^2\delta+(\beta\delta)^2\alpha+(\alpha\delta)^2\beta+(\beta\gamma)^2\alpha+(\alpha\gamma)^2\beta+(\beta\alpha)^2\gamma}{\alpha\beta \gamma \delta}$ ? Now, how to make it in the desired form ?

Answer (score 1):

By [Viète's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are:
$$e_1=\sum\alpha=-p,\quad e_2=\sum\alpha\beta=q,\quad e_3=\sum\alpha\beta\gamma=-r,\quad
e_4=\alpha\beta\gamma\delta=s.$$

Multiplying our sum of *fractions* by the common denominator $e_4,$ we get a symmetric *polynomial*:
$$e_4\sum\frac{\alpha\beta}\gamma=\sum\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\frac{\alpha\beta}\gamma=\sum\alpha^2\beta^2\delta=\sum\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma.$$

By the [fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), $\sum\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma$ is a polynomial function of the $e_i$'s. To find out this (unique) function, apply one of the many algorithms. My favorite one is [the one based on the lexicographic order on the (tuples of) exponents](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_fondamental_des_fonctions_sym%C3%A9triques#Proc%C3%A9dures_de_calcul):

- Start from the exponents in $\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma:$ $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)=(2,2,1,0).$
- Set $t_i:=\alpha_i-\alpha_{i+1}$ for $i<4:$ $t_1=0,t_2=1,t_3=1,$ and $t_4:=\alpha_4=0.$
- Compute $\prod e_i^{t_i}-\sum\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma=\sum\alpha\beta\sum\alpha\beta\gamma-\sum\alpha^2\beta^2\gamma=3\sum\alpha^2\beta\gamma\delta.$
- Iterate on this new symmetric polynomial (whose exponent is lexicographically  smaller), obtaining similarly: $\sum\alpha^2\beta\gamma\delta=e_1e_4.$

The final result is:
$$\sum\frac{\alpha\beta}\gamma=\frac{e_2e_3-3e_1e_4}{e_4}=\frac{-qr}s+3p.$$